# RestSharp response unauthorized

Tags: console-application, restsharp

I am new to web based solutions. I am hitting a rest url using RestSharp library.
My code is as follows:

```
var cleint = new RestClient("http://REST_URL");
cleint.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("username", "password");
var request = new RestRequest();
request.Method = Method.GET;
request.Resource = "0.json";

IRestResponse response = cleint.Execute(request);
if (response != null && ((response.StatusCode ==       HttpStatusCode.OK) &&
(response.ResponseStatus == ResponseStatus.Completed)))
  {
  // var arr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>    (response.Content);

  }
```

The url returns a json file, when I hit it manually. But I want to use a C# console application to get the json file and save it to the disk. I am getting an unauthorized response when I run the above mentioned code:
 `response.ResponseStatus= "Unauthorized"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is all it needed..

```
  client.Authenticator = new NtlmAuthenticator();
```

So if your IIS settings have Windows Authentication set as enabled, this is what you are going to need, Http Basic authentication is not enough to by pass the server security

Comment: For me its not working with version 108