# Deserialize JSON response using RestSharp result in null object

Tags: c#, json, rest, api, restsharp

I am trying to consume a REST API using RestSharp and deserialize to my User class.

This is my JSON response:

```
   [
      {
        "AdName": "sample string 1",
        "Email": "sample string 2",
        "Name": "sample string 3"
      },
      {
        "AdName": "sample string 1",
        "Email": "sample string 2",
        "Name": "sample string 3"
      }
    ]
```

This is the API client:

```
public class SamTApi
{
    const string BaseUrl = "http://localhost:8097/SamT_WebApi/api/User";


    public T Execute<T>(RestRequest request) where T : new()
    {
        var client = new RestClient();
        client.AddHandler("application/json", new JsonDeserializer());
        client.BaseUrl = new Uri(BaseUrl);

        var response = client.Execute<T>(request);

        return response.Data;
    }

    public List<User> GetUser()
    {
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
        return Execute<List<User>>(request);
    }
}
```

This is my User class:

```
public class User
{
    public string AdName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class UserResponse
{
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

So when I try to assert:

```
var api = new SamTApi();
var users = api.GetUser();
Assert.IsNotNull(users, "users != null");
```

It results in users = null. I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: I'm not a RestSharp expert but I don't think you need to `AddHandler`, I think it uses json deserialization by default. You have confirmed through debugging that `response.Data` is the JSON?

Comment: You are right, the `AddHandler` is redundant. It actually chooses the deserializer based upon the Content-Type returned. I found out my response was returning null because of authentication. Found the answer here. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29544824/restsharp-response-unauthorized)Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Use Newtonsoft Json nuget package. When you install it just call:

```c#
var destinationObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DestinationClass>(json);
```